# jQuery + AJAX + This Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I find **ID/Class** of the current form within the ajax success function? Since there are multiple forms with the same Class, I cant simply search for the class, but need exactly the form that was submitted.

I have following script:

```
$('#fAddOs,#fAddFs,.addJ').submit(function(){

    //$(this) = form

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'admin.inc.php',
        data:data,
        dataType:'html',
        success:
        function(response){
            //Get form
        }
    });

});
```

If I call `$(this)` within the AJAX function (see my comment in the code above), I get:

```
[Object { url="admin.inc.php", isLocal=false, global=true, mehr...}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

outside the ajax call, save the form to a variable that you can use inside the ajax callback.

```
$('#fAddOs,#fAddFs,.addJ').submit(function(){

    var form = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'admin.inc.php',
        data:data,
        dataType:'html',
        success:
        function(response){
            // use the form variable here...
            console.log(form.attr('id'));
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Man, how could i not come up with this. its so obvious! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

With the selector you're using, you are grabbing multiple elements. Inside the submit, the current form being worked with can be accessed using `this`. Or to use it as a jQuery object `$(this)`.

In the function:

```
var id = $(this).attr("id");
```

Or to grab the class name

```
var class = $(this).attr("class");
```

**UPDATE**

Before the ajax call, create a var:

```
var form = $(this);
```

then use `form` in the ajax function

Comment: This was it^^ I cant belive I didnt think of setting the var before the ajax call...

Answer (score 0):

Try this within the submit function:

```
var id = this.id;
```